# Custom stack view alignment

Tags: swift, uikit, uistackview

[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit
import TinyConstraints

final class CountDownStackView: UIStackView {
    func configure(withData data: [[String]]) {
           data.forEach { rowData in
               let verticalStackView = UIStackView()
               verticalStackView.axis = .vertical
               verticalStackView.spacing = 8
               
               rowData.forEach { text in
                   let label = UILabel()
                   label.text = text
                   label.backgroundColor = .lightGray
                   label.textAlignment = .center
                   verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
               }
               
               let horizontalStackView = UIStackView()
               horizontalStackView.axis = .horizontal
               horizontalStackView.spacing = 5
               
               horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(verticalStackView)
               
               let parser = UILabel()
               parser.text = ":"
               parser.customizeLabel(font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18),textColor: .white)
               horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(parser)
               
               addArrangedSubview(horizontalStackView)
           }
       }
    }
```

I'm using this code blog and I can't find where I went wrong and where I need to fix it.

the first image is the result of my codes, but I am trying to capture the situation in the second image

```
  let data: [[String]] = [
        ["02", " Hour"],
        ["43","minute"],
        ["23","second"]]
```

sample data

Comment: Why are you creating a custom `UIStackView` subclass? What issue are you having? What's the first picture in your question? Is that the result of your code? But your goal is the second picture?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the first visual is the result of my codes and the second is the situation I want to capture exactly what information you want to know extra? I have to do it with UIStackView subclass, this is what is required of me

Comment: So, probably, you want the subclass to be the horizontal stack view

Comment: In fact, the main stack view should be horizontal and the sub stack views should be vertical. I don't know, I'm very confused, the problem is exactly visible in the visuals.

Comment: Don’t create any horizontal stack views. Setup `self` as the only horizontal stack view. Separately, how do you plan to be able to update the timer with this setup?

Comment: How would you build this place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one horizontal stack view but your code will create 3. Since `self` is already a stack view, `self` should be the one and only horizontal stack view. Here's a rework of your class:

```swift
final class CountDownStackView: UIStackView {
    func configure(withData data: [[String]]) {
        axis = .horizontal
        distribution = .equalSpacing
        alignment = .center
        spacing = 5

        for (column, rowData) in data.enumerated() {
            var labels = [UILabel]()
            for (row, text) in rowData.enumerated() {
                let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
                label.font = row == 0 ? .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1) : .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
                label.textColor = column + 1 == data.count ? .systemGray : .label
                label.text = text
                label.textAlignment = .left
                labels.append(label)
            }
            let verticalStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: labels)
            verticalStackView.axis = .vertical
            verticalStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
            verticalStackView.alignment = .leading
            verticalStackView.spacing = 4

            addArrangedSubview(verticalStackView)

            if column + 1 < data.count {
                let parser = UILabel()
                parser.text = ":"
                parser.customizeLabel(font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18), textColor: .label)
                parser.sizeToFit()
                addArrangedSubview(parser)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it with something like:

```swift
let data: [[String]] = [
    ["02", "Hour"],
    ["43", "Minute"],
    ["23", "Second"],
]

let stack = CountDownStackView()
stack.configure(withData: data)
```

This gives you a layout that is much closer to the 2nd picture. But the two colons don't look right. I would add the colons as strings in your `data` array. Update the class as follows:

```swift
final class CountDownStackView: UIStackView {
    func configure(withData data: [[String]]) {
        axis = .horizontal
        distribution = .equalSpacing
        alignment = .center
        spacing = 5

        for (column, rowData) in data.enumerated() {
            var labels = [UILabel]()
            for (row, text) in rowData.enumerated() {
                let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
                label.font = row == 0 ? .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1) : .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
                label.textColor = column + 1 == data.count ? .systemGray : .label
                label.text = text
                label.textAlignment = .left
                labels.append(label)
            }
            let verticalStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: labels)
            verticalStackView.axis = .vertical
            verticalStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
            verticalStackView.alignment = .leading
            verticalStackView.spacing = 4

            addArrangedSubview(verticalStackView)
        }
    }
}
```

Then create it as follows:

```swift
let data: [[String]] = [
    ["02", "Hour"],
    [":", " "],
    ["43", "Minute"],
    [":", " "],
    ["23", "Second"],
]

let stack = CountDownStackView()
stack.configure(withData: data)
```

This gives a better result with the layout.

While this answer gives you a solution to the layout issues with your custom stack view subclass, I would suggest that this whole approach is far from ideal for implementing some sort of countdown view. Your current `CountDownStackView` makes it very difficult to update any of the labels as the timer counts down.

While I'll leave the details for another question (since this is beyond the scope of your original question), you really should create a subclass of `UIView` that makes use of a stack view of labels. It should also use a `Timer` that can be used to update the labels in the stack view.